# Nested Gallery Shortcode INTERMITTENTLY working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nested, shortcode

I have an Expand/ Collapse plugin which, via a shortcode, can expand/ collapse content. My expandable content is a shortcode of a gallery.

See here: http://shop.dearearth.net/collections

INTERMITTENTLY, the gallery shows up in at least the first to be expanded section, but never in the second...

Any help on this would really be appreciated, of course! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem, but the shortcode "parsing code" is seriously f*cked up. There are all sorts of special cases (which really aren't that special) where it either a) doesn't work at all, or b) does something completely different from what you would expect.

Two examples:

- `[shortcode][shortcode]` (without a space in between) will ignore the second one.
- `[shortcode] [shortcode] [/shortcode]` will *not* do what you want, even though it is technically "correct".

The fundamental problem is that they have "created" ("stumbled into" might be a better description) a syntax that is inherently un-parsable. And then ... they are trying to parse it with regexp. This is doomed to failure -- it is actually worse than trying to [parse HTML with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), difficult as that might seem.

The only true solution to this is to get rid of the bizarre legacy syntax and then replace the current "parser" with one that actually works. Interactions on the dev group mailing list show no indication that they realize how far down a dead end they have traveled.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15366/nested-gallery-shortcode-intermittently-working